# How can I force a "save as" option when the user clicks a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, save

I have a link to a PDF on my web page and I want to know if it's possible to always ask the user if they want to download the PDF or open it in a new window. Is this possible? I realise that people would not want the PDF to automatically download, but 2 links or an option would be great.

There is quite a lot of documentation about this on the internet, some even saying I'd have to have PHP and this is not possible on the server I use.

I need a javascript, jQuery solution or alternative suggestion. Not asking for much I know.

Thanks very much for reading this and I hope it makes sense.

All the best! 
T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done, but not in clientside javascript. If you have a server side script that feeds the file, it can send a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header along with the response. This will trigger a save as dialog in the browser.

If they are static files, you can also change the configuration of your server. For Apache use the [FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#filesmatch) directive. There's a nice example for PDF files here:

http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7045

Comment: Hi there, do I have to specify the name of this file if I use this option? It's dynamically generated... Thanks for a great answer :)

Comment: You don't have to, although it is possible. In addition to this header you can specify the `filename` header. The name you specify there, is the name that browsers will suggest in the save as dialog. The name doesn't necessarily have to match the name on the server. Even better: there doesn't even have to be a pdf file on disk on the server. The contents can be generated and sent to the client with a filename header without there ever being a real pdf file on the server.

Comment: Added a bit about the FilesMatch directive.