# content disposition not opening save as

Tags: html, meta-tags, content-disposition

Hi I'm trying to make a link open the save as dialog when it is clicked and I have read that you can do it using content disposition.

I have the following link:

```
<a href="/documents/example-name.pdf">Pdf name has dashes (not sure if this makes a difference)</a>
```

and I added the following meta tags to the header (of the page with the link in it):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-disposition" content="attachment" />
<meta name="content-disposition" content="attachment; filename=example-name.pdf" />
```

But it still opens the pdf rather than opening the save as dialog.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you add these meta tags ? In the page that contains the link ?

If you put these meta tags in the header of that page it won't work because these headers are for the html page not the pdf. If you want to open the dialog you must use a page (php, asp.net,...) that returns the pdf and add the headers in the pdf http response

[How can I force a "save as" option when the user clicks a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429505/how-can-i-force-a-save-as-option-when-the-user-clicks-a-link/8429521#8429521)

Comment: Yes, at the top of the page in the header section, ps this should be a comment rather than an answer

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment and i have only 26 ;-)

Comment: I was trying to avoid making a controller for forcing the dialog to open as it's only one pdf I'm needing to do this for but I guess that'll have to do